# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined у забинженной модели

Tags: angular

Подскажите, а это нормально, что в момент отображения формы, если модель, которая биндится еще не получена(например, запросил с сервера), то консоль пестрит ошибками:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Я нашел решение в виде использования оператора `.?`, но правильно его использовать или есть другой грамотный путь?

`<app-test [name]="model?.name"></app-test>`

Comment: странный вопрос без какой либо информации))

Comment: @overthesanity, как без какой? Есть модель, создается после выполнение запроса к Api. Пока модель не создана Angular при биндинге не может забиндить поля так как их еще не существует. Собственно, я спрашиваю, а нормально на все подряд вешать заглушку в виде ".?" или у меня что-то не так?:)

Comment: вы же знаете что я всегда что-то говорю когда вижу весь набор информации в полной мере)) покажите шаблон хотя бы, я в данный момент в разных контекстах и хотел бы видеть проблему

Comment: @overthesanity добавил.

Comment: лучше всего не работать с "optinal" типами данных, либо проводить иницализацию модели в конструкторе обычным объектом `model = {}`, тогда `model.name` будет `undefined` и не будет эксепшенов

Comment: много писать, лучше оставлю подробный ответ

Comment: @overthesanity есть вопрос, немного офтотоп. Подскажите, а какими средствами Angular я могу воспользоваться, что бы пулять алерты наподобие таких https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview, но без использования material? Это динамическое создание компонентов? Что почитать можно?

Comment: iluxa, yep, это динамические компоненты, так работает материал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я лично не сторонник "safe navigation" оператора и скажу вам честно - за все время разработки на Angular я его ни разу не использовал (не потому что не знаю как им пользоваться).

Нужно просто стараться грамотно выстраивать потоки данных и исключить возможность коммуникации с `null` и `undefined` значениями для компонентов. Во всех проекта я использую флаги компилятора `strictNullChecks` и `strictPropertyInitialization` (вообще можно просто `strict` задать, он автоматически задаст сабсет опций), а также можно задавать опции Angular компилятора (не TS).

Более глубокие проверки на `null` и `undefined` уже может совершать сам компилятор Angular, для этого в `src/tsconfig.app.json` нужно добавить опцию `angularCompilerOptions`:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts"],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true
  }
}
```

В самим компонентах вам нужно будет явно указывать, что данное свойство может быть `undefined`. То есть:

```
public person: Person;
```

Не прокатит:

> Property 'person' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

Тогда нужно будет использовать "optional" оператор:

```
public person?: Person;
```

Либо явно эсайнить значение в `null` или `undefined` (я юзаю `null` всегда):

```
public person: Person | null = null;
```

P.S. - тип `Person | null` указывается в том случае если вы уверены, что свойство МОЖЕТ БЫТЬ `null`, если вы 100% уверены в том, что свойству будет присвоено какое-то значение в будущем, то используйте оператор `not-null` утверждения:

```
public person: Person = null!;
```

Как пример где его использовать:

```
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input()
  public type: 'primary' | 'secondary' = null!;
}
```

Здесь вы 100% уверены в том, что биндинг `type` передаст разработчик, иначе кнопка неверно отрендерится.

К чему была вся эта демагогия про типизацию? Angular компилятор будет кидать экспешены, если вы пытаетесь достучаться к свойству объекта, который может быть `null`. Идем по вашему примеру, у свойства `model` должен быть какой-то тип:

```
public model: Model | null = null;
```

Шаблон:

```
[name]="model.name"
```

Angular компилятор кинет эксепшн:

> ERROR in src/app/some.component.html(3,5): : Object is possibly 'null'.

То есть компилятор вас посредством эксепшенов заставляет использовать операторы "safe navigation" или "not-null assetion":

```
[name]="model?.name"

// OR

[name]="model!.name"
```

Можно еще привести к `any` в шаблоне, но это совсем шлак и такое никогда не нужно использовать:

```
[name]="$any(model).name"
```

Я использую в основном `ngIf`:

```
*ngIf="model" [name]="model.name"
```

Но по бест практисам байндинги лучше не передавать по ссылкам, типа `model.name`, а лучше передавать весь объект целиком:

```
[model]="model"
```

Бест практис по той причине, что так работает стратегия обнаружения изменений `OnPush`, которая скажет компоненту зависеть только от входных параметров и ререндерить в случаях, когда ссылка на входной параметр изменилась.

Comment: 'Нужно просто стараться грамотно выстраивать потоки данных и исключить возможность коммуникации с null и undefined значениями для компонентов.' ну вот у меня в компоненте должны отрендерится данные, которые я запросил через HttpClient но мог еще не успеть получить. Разве тут как-то можно в этом случае избежать нуллов и грамотно все выставить?

Comment: потому что данные нельзя грузить во время инициализации компонентов, данные уже должны быть готовы, это то что я говорил вам про резолверы

Comment: ну гугл в своем примере тоже данные через сервис напрямую тянут https://stackblitz.com/angular/lrgbklxpqal?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fhero-list%2Fhero-list.component.ts . во

Comment: это пример для новичков

Comment: Ладно, нужно поковыряться в них. Может вы на этот вопрос ответите еще? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/963905/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-angular-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE

Comment: я не совсем понимаю этот вопрос :))

Comment: Ну типа есть какой-то компонент. Можно ли ему задать стиль из родительского компонента если наружу он не выставил свойств для этого.

Comment: нуууу, вы же можете через css задать его?

Comment: По идее, только через глобальный CSS, что, наверное, плохо.

Comment: почему? есть `::ng-deep` + зачем оно вам? если компонент реюзабл то должна быть возможность его конфигурировать как вам нужно через биндинги и тд

Comment: Еще вопрос про ресолвер: а если у меня компонент(Назовем его Container), который представляет собой выбор категорий, список которого запрашивается с сервера и другой компонент(назовем его ContenBrowser), который имеет Input() categoryId и в зависимости от него запрашивает данные из сервиса на каждую смену categoryId и рендерит свое содержимое. Container передает выбранные данные в ContenBrowser. Ну и при первом рендере ContenBrowser очевидно, что не все данные будут готовы.

Comment: Я же правильно понимаю, что единственное, что я могу сделать в данном случае, что бы избежать Cannot read property - это выполнить инициализацию в конструкторе дефолтными значениями или на этот счет у Ангулар есть еще какое-то решение? Или может быть я что-то не так делаю и есть другой правильный путь?

Comment: значит не показывать contenbrowser пока данные не готовы или грузить их заранее